# Python Selenium accessing elements with similar classes

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on this element using python-selenium bindings .There are multiple elements with the same class but different data-original-title attribute .

How can I access these elements with data-original-title="Like" directly ?
instead of having to fetch first by class names then loop through elements for desired attribute .

HTML code

`<div class="IconContainer js-tooltip" data-original-title="Like">`

Comment: Are you saying elements that have a data-original-title attribute always have a unique value for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium / Python - Selecting via css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600391/selenium-python-selecting-via-css-selector)

Answer (score 1):

If you meant that the attribute `data-original-title` is always unique, you can select the element with the desired attribute value using xpath:

```
//div[@data-original-title='Like']
```