# Selecting a drop down option in Selenium with data-bind value

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to select an item from a drop-down element using Selenium but the only unique ID is in the data-bind value. I have tried using

```
<select data-bind="value: customerProvince, options: availableProvinces, optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: ''" class="form-control uc-not-searchable" size="1">
```

```
<option value=""></option><option value="">Alberta</option><option value="">British Columbia</option><option value="">Manitoba</option><option value="">New Brunswick</option><option value="">Newfoundland and Labrador</option><option value="">Northwest Territories</option><option value="">Nova Scotia</option><option value="">Nunavut</option><option value="">Ontario</option><option value="">Prince Edward Island</option><option value="">Quebec</option><option value="">Saskatchewan</option><option value="">Yukon Territory</option>
                        </select>
```

I would then like to select an option value. I have tried both pieces of the following code to no avail:

```
customerProvinceField = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("value: customerProvince, options: availableProvinces, optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: ''")

customerProvinceField = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("value: customerProvince")
```

Both receive an error of: "Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified".

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium / Python - Selecting via css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600391/selenium-python-selecting-via-css-selector)

Answer (score 0):

Use below :-

```
customerProvinceField= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[contains(@data-bind,"value: customerProvince, options: availableProvinces, optionsText:")]')
```

Code will be like

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[contains(@data-bind,"value: customerProvince, options: availableProvinces, optionsText:")]')).select_by_value('Nunavut').click()
```

refer :-

[Selecting a value from a drop-down option using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524621/selecting-a-value-from-a-drop-down-option-using-selenium-python)

Hope it will help you